# Format date with moment

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date, angular9

A similar question was asked in all languages except JS.
Depending on the variable day, I need to know if variable day today, or tomorrow or other days?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need momentJS for this simple task
You Need To Supply a needed date to the calculate function.

```
 let calculate = (date: Date) => {
    let now = new Date();
    if (date.getMonth() == now.getMonth() && date.getFullYear() == now.getFullYear()) {
        if (date.getDate() == now.getDate()) {
            return "Yey, Today"
        }
        if (date.getDate() == now.getDate() + 1) {
            return "Yey, tomorrow"

        }
        return "Other Date"
    }
    return "Other Date"

}
```